# Are blockciphers with 64-bit blocks still relevant (in any scenario)?

Tags: block-cipher, blocksize

**Facts**

1. Blockciphers are used to build encryption algorithms and compression functions for hash algorithms.
2. (Unkeyed) Permutations are also complementing blockciphers in encryption and hashing.
3. Large block sizes are preferred.
4. **But** There are embedded/IoT/lightweight systems.
5. There are still mode of operations defined for 64-bit blocks AND there are still 64-bit blockciphers with key lengths that're considered secure (e.g. IDEA).

**My question**

Are blockciphers with 64-bit blocks still relevant?

---

Age-old update:

Is this a dupe of [that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/105982/36960) or vice versa?

Comment: Think it is a dupe, but the new question got some answers so not sure what the procedure is there.